# jQuery .each function with if condition works for first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have HTML content (actually a WordPress plugin's tab like this) -

```
<div class="store-tabs">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="https://example.com/store/">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://example.com/store/reviews">Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to add the "Active" class to the link element if I am on the matching URL. My problem is that the condition only works for the first element but the second element does not get the class. Here is my jQuery -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
  var url      = window.location.href;

  $('.store-tabs .list-inline li a').each(function(){

    var current = $(this).attr('href');

    if (current == url) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }

   });

});
```

**UPDATE**

The code was right but my URLs did not have the matching trailing slash at the end. I have fixed it by adding the slash on the fly (the URLs are auto-generated) -

```
if(current.slice(current.length - 1) != '/') {
      current = current + '/';
    }
```

Thanks, everyone :)

Comment: You could maybe try with `if (url.indexOf(current) > -1)`

Comment: I will have more than two tabs. This I believe can check only against specific values.

Comment: Please post the debug output of your developer tools, created by adding `console.log({ current, url });` to your each-callback. This will help us all to find the error and give all necessary information to help you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`https://example.com/store/reviews` is not equal to `https://example.com/store/reviews/`.
Try to add '/' to the end of your `href="https://example.com/store/reviews"`

Comment: Omg! this is absolutely correct! The trailing "/" was not matched.